# Invoke pipeline when file is placed in on prem server

Tags: azure-data-factory

How to invoke a pipeline in azure data factory when a file is placed in on prem server?

I have no idea. any suggestions would be highly appreciated

Comment: can you share more informationabout what you are trying

Comment: we have a on-prem server where files are placed daily, we need to trigger a pipeline (which copies data from on-prem to adls) when ever a file is placed in on prem server.

Comment: In ADF there are storage event triggers are available blob storage and adls to achive your requirement you need to create logic app trigger to trigger ADF pipeline when new file is added.

Comment: I was wondering about on-prem not adls. let me explain once again, when ever the file is placed in on prem server, we need to trigger pipeline

Comment: To fulfill your requirement, first you need to create a logic app trigger which detect the file is added or modified in local server then from there you can trigger the ADF pipeline to coy data of that file from on-prem to adls. In ADF trigger there are storage even trigger the also do the same thing detect file added or modifies and then trigger the pipeline but it is only for azure file system like blob storage and adls

Comment: okay ,let me check on this. thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if the storage event trigger work in this as the storage is in-prem .
If I were you I could have tried to explore  the popwershell cmdlet
Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/invoke-azdatafactoryv2pipeline?view=azps-9.7.1

I think you can keep monitoring a folder locally and as soon as you have a file , you can trigger a ADF pipeline using the above mentioned pipeline. .